# Running a Simple Falcon App

Tags: python, gunicorn, falconframework

I've a simple falcon app straight from the getting started example

```
import falcon
import json


class QuoteResource:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        """Handles GET requests"""
        quote = {
            'quote': 'I\'ve always been more interested in the future than in the past.',
            'author': 'Grace Hopper'
        }

        resp.body = json.dumps(quote)


api = falcon.API()
api.add_route('/quote', QuoteResource())
```

The code is in a file called `manage.py`

When I try to run `gunicorn manage:app`
This is what I get

```
2017-06-04 20:47:18 -0700] [2370] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-06-04 20:47:18 -0700] [2370] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2370)
[2017-06-04 20:47:18 -0700] [2370] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-06-04 20:47:18 -0700] [2373] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2373
Failed to find application: 'manage'
[2017-06-04 20:47:18 -0700] [2373] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2373)
[2017-06-04 20:47:18 -0700] [2370] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-06-04 20:47:18 -0700] [2370] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether it is a typo or because of misunderstanding but you should start the application this way:

```
gunicorn manage:api
```

But not `gunicorn manage:app`

The `manage:api` option tells to invoke the `api` object defined in your manage.py module. Otherwise you need to rename `api` variable to `app` in your code.

Then you can check that application is running by accessing the following url:

```
http://localhost:8000/quote
```

By default the port should `8000` but you need to check it when gunicorn starts. It should be something like this:

```
[INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000
```